Batch multiple if statement and goto
I have this file:
\begin{flushleft}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
\end{flushleft}

And I'd like turn it into
text removed
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
another text remove

via batch.
Yes, I know there's a plenty of question like this. In fact, I made this code taking inspiration from from the various questions
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=merged.tex
set OutputFile=merged-new.tex

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "\begin{flushleft}" (echo text removed) else (echo %%A)
  )
)
MOVE %OutputFile% %InputFile%

This code works fine for the first substituction. But waht if I'like to insert a second condition if "%%A" equ "\end{flushleft}" and replace this string with another (perhaps different from "text removed") how can I do it? I tried with
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=merged.tex
set OutputFile=merged-new.tex

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "\begin{flushleft}" goto :beginflushleft
    if "%%A" equ "\end{flushleft}" goto :endflushleft
    
    :beginflushleft
    echo text removed
    
    :endflushleft
    echo another text removed
  )
)
MOVE %OutputFile% %InputFile%

But what I get is a file with an multiple sequence of
text removed
another text removed


@Squashman question updated

Notwithstanding the fact that you cannot have labels within a for loop, you have only told the code what to do for two of the lines. You need to tell it what to do with %%A in the other scenario!

This solution allows a simple (and fast!) processing of a large number of different replacements:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Define the set of replacements
set "num=0"
for %%a in ("\begin{flushleft}=text removed"
            "\end{flushleft}=another text removed"
            "\raggedright=and another one"
           ) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do (
      set /A num+=1
      set "find[!num!]=%%b"
      set "repl[!num!]=%%c"
   )
)

:Variables
set InputFile=merged.tex
set OutputFile=merged-new.tex

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
   set "i="
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%num%) do if not defined i (
      if "%%A" == "!find[%%i]!" set "i=%%i"
   )
   if defined i (
      for %%i in (!i!) do echo !repl[%%i]!
   ) else (
      echo %%A
   )
)
)
MOVE %OutputFile% %InputFile%

The only problem is if the text to be find/replaced contains a question mark ? or asterisk * because such characters interfere with the FOR command. If this happens, just initialize the find/replace text in individual lines (outside the FOR command).

This becomes untenable if you have multiple find and replaces. You would be better off with a hybrid script like Dave Benham's JREPL.bat
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=merged.tex
set OutputFile=merged-new.tex

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" == "\begin{flushleft}" (
        echo text removed
    ) else if "%%A" == "\end{flushleft}" (
        echo another text removed
    ) else (
        echo %%A
    )
)
)
MOVE %OutputFile% %InputFile%

Another option is to chain together conditional execution.
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=merged.tex
set OutputFile=merged-new.tex

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo %%A|findstr /B/E "\begin{flushleft}" >nul 2>&1 && (
        echo text removed
    ) || (
    echo %%A|findstr /B/E "\end{flushleft}" >nul 2>&1 && (
        echo more text removed
    ) || (
        echo %%A
    )
    )
)
)
MOVE %OutputFile% %InputFile%

Either one of these options can be extended to multiple checks.

I took the liberty of correcting the formatting of the code...  ;)  +1

I have to say that the new "chain together conditional execution" solution is much slower than the first one. In the second solution a pipe with findstr,exe command at right side must be executed for each of the replacements. Every line with no replacements requires the execution of two pipes/findstr commands. If the file is large, the difference in execution time will be very noticeable...

You have no flow control in your loop. For any condition other than if "%%A" equ "\end{flushleft}" goto :endflushleft execution will simply continue through the different echo statements. You don't need the labels and goto clauses at all.
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=merged.tex
set OutputFile=merged-new.tex

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "\begin{flushleft}" (
        echo text removed
    )

    if "%%A" equ "\end{flushleft}" (
        echo another text removed
    )
  )
)
MOVE %OutputFile% %InputFile%


This code returns a file with only the lines I want replace. What about the rest of the file else (echo %%A)?

question updated
